# IE11 - Registry key to enable menu bar and favorites bar to all users

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, internet-explorer-11

I am upgrading Windows-7 Service Pack-1, 32-bit computers from Internet Explorer-8 to Internet Explorer-11.  After the upgrade is complete, the Menu bar and Favorites bars do not show up when non-admin users log in.  Right click and selecting the menu and favorite bars, only works for the user logged in.

I want those two menus to show up as default, so the new browser matches the old settings.

Does anyone know a registry key that I can create that will keep the Menu and Favorites bar displayed for all users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MINIE
```

- LinksBandEnabled to **1**
- AlwaysShowMenus to **1**

**.reg** file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MINIE]
"LinksBandEnabled"=dword:00000001
"AlwaysShowMenus"=dword:00000001
```

Use a GPO to deploy that to all users, or however you want to force the keys.

Comment: This doesnt tattoo the registry either. Its good. I just tested it on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0.16299.15).